# Vanilla Javascript extends class and use it on page

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I am working with vanilla JS ( no Node )

I got 2 classes in 2 different files. User.js and Admin.js
Then I got MainController.js and index.php.

I would like to `import` user to admin and extend admin. Then extend mainController by those 2 classes and use its code on page. Problem is when I try to extend any `class` inside in mainController, its undefined and I cant use it on page. Unless I just import it without extending any classes, I can start functions written in mainController but I cant access it from script nor console.

I would like to import all classes from User and Admin to MainController and use that on page so index wont have multiple script tags.

If all files would be in 1 file, it wouldn't be a problem to add everything to 1 class and use it. Problem is with multiple files.

Example:

User

```
class User {
constructor(username, email){
    // Set up properties
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.score = 0;
}.....
```

Admin

```
import User from './user.js';
export default class Admin extends User {

constructor(username, email, title){
    super(username, email);
    this.title = title;
}....
```

MainController

```
import User from './user'
import Admin from "./admin";
class mainController extends User & Admin {

constructor(username, email, title){
    super(username, email);
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

Index.php

```
<script src=maincontroller.js></script>
<script> const xxx = new User()...</script>
```

Comment: What is `mainController extends User & Admin`?

Comment: Do your `import`s work? They should not unless you use a transpiler for your modules. Doesn't look like an inheritance problem to me.

Comment: Node is "vanilla" javascript. It's just a framework that runs JS.

Comment: @adiga. Thats just example of what I wanna achive
Liam. I know but I prefere to keep it simple so no node

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with the way you attempt to implement `class` inheritance. `Admin` already `extends` `User`, so there is no point to try and specify that a third `class` that `extends` `Admin` need to also extend `User`. That is already specified when you state that the third `class` extends `Admin` due to the mere fact that `Admin` `extends` `User`.

So, that `&` is syntactically invalid and logically unnecessary, syntactical fix:

```
class mainController extends Admin {

    constructor(username, email, title){
        super(username, email);
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

That being said, we need to understand that the name of `mainController` and `Admin` seem to be completely unrelated in terms of `class` hierarchy, because `mainController` seems to be a controller and `User`/`Admin` seem to be model classes. So, to me it seems that you want `mainController` to operate with `User`/`Admin` objects and you seem to think that you need to extend those classes in order to achieve this. If I'm right, then in `mainController` you probably need to work with instances of these classes as parameters / variables / data members.

Comment: So if I got it right, mainController is pointless. Still I got a problem with using admin class inside index.php. 
I got it as <script type=module> but if I made "let x = new Admin()" it says that admin is not defined and if I use Script without type=module, "You cannot import data outsite of a module". So I have no idea what to do

Comment: @Virus mainController is not necessarily pointless. Judging by its name it seems that you do not need to extend Admin with it. When you say that a class extends another one, then a general rule is that the class that extends the other is a specific subcase of the more general class. Admin is a User, so it makes sense that Admin extends User. But mainController is not really an Admin. Can you show us the part of your markup where you put in your scripts?

Comment: I can show but all I do in maincontroller is import user and admin. I dont write another class nor any more code. I just wanted to add both as 1 script tag instead of few. 
After your comments I get it, Its pointiless. Much thx 4 exmplanation

Comment: I wonder how you put in your script tags into the structure @Virus. Maybe there is a problem at that point.